# Estimate of parameter $\beta$

Tags: r, estimation, frailty

Suppose I've a set of information,

> ```
> id t  s   x          H0         h0        H0i         Hi Di       Eu          Elu
>  1 2  1  53  0.01067033 0.01067033 0.01371871 0.01371871  2 1.039715  0.029300175
>  2 4  0  60  0.02148908 0.01081875 0.02856059 0.04227930  1 1.019138  0.009121439
>  3 5  0  45  0.04344224 0.02195316 0.05377424 0.09605354  2 1.038006  0.027655283
>  4 5  0  50  0.04344224 0.02195316 0.05506429 0.15111783  2 1.036866  0.026556713
>  5 6  0  52  0.05472922 0.01128698 0.07003181 0.22114964  2 1.035420  0.025161271
>  6 7  1  51  0.07763398 0.02290476 0.09887098 0.32002062  2 1.033386  0.023194494
> ```

If I want to find the estimate of $\beta$ from this,

> $$  Q(\beta)=\sum_{i=1}^{G}\sum_{j=1}^{n_{i}}[\delta_{ij}\{\ln
>  h_{o}(t_{ij})+\beta'x_{ij}+E(\log U_{i})\}-H_{o}(t_{ij})e^{\beta'x_{ij}}E(U_{i})]
> $$
>   where, 
>   $t_{ij}$ is the $j^\mathrm{th}$ time point of the $i\mathrm{th}$ individual, $\delta_{ij}$ is the status, $x_{ij}$ is the vector of covariates.

Let initial $\beta$ be 0.02. How can we find the estimate of $\beta$ using R code?

Comment: How is $\hat{\beta}$ defined? Is it defined by $Q(\hat{\beta}) = 0$? Or by $Q'(\hat{\beta}) = 0$? By the way, does this have something to do with frailty models?

Comment: $Q'(\hat{\beta})=0$. Yes, it, is one part of M-step in shared frailty model. I am trying to do it in a way, but facing some problem for double summation and do not get the exact value.

Comment: I have added the 'frailty' tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Some background*

Using standard notations, the Cox model is defined as
$$h(t) = h_0(t) \exp(\mathbf{x}^\prime \mathbf{\beta})$$
and the associated likelihood is
\begin{align*}
L(\mathbf{\beta}, h_0; \textrm{data}) 
  & = \prod_{j=1}^n h_j(y_j)^{\delta_j} S_j(y_j) \\
  & = \prod_{j=1}^n \left(h_0(t) \exp(\mathbf{x}^\prime_j \mathbf{\beta})\right)^{\delta_j}
      \exp \left( -H_0(y_j) \exp(\mathbf{x}^\prime_j \mathbf{\beta}) \right).
\end{align*}
The log-likelihood is thus given by
$$
\ell(\mathbf{\beta}, h_0; \textrm{data}) = 
  \sum_{j=1}^n \delta_j \left[\log(h_0(y_j)) + \mathbf{x}^\prime_j \mathbf{\beta} \right]
  - H_0(y_j) \exp(\mathbf{x}^\prime_j \mathbf{\beta}).
$$

If $h_0$ is known (up to some parameters), this can be maximised in `R` using, e.g., ['survreg()'](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/survival/html/survreg.html). On the other hand, if $h_0$ is left unspecified, then $\ell(\mathbf{\beta}, h_0; \textrm{data})$ has first to profiled into a partial log-likelihood, and the latter can be maximised in `R` using, e.g., [coxph()](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/survival/html/coxph.html).

---

Your $Q(\mathbf{\beta})$ is basically the same as $\ell(\mathbf{\beta}, h_0; \textrm{data})$, except that the $\textrm{E}(\log(U_i))$'s enter as fixed offset terms. You can therefore rely on existing software since it is possible to [include an offset in a model formula](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/offset.html).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But, I want to do it in step by step R function, not built in R code. So, I need to optimize the $Q(\beta)$.

Comment: In that case, you need to enter minus the likelihood into R (Q <- function(beta, data) {... }) and then to rely on an optimisation routine like 'nml' or 'optim'.

Comment: Thanks. I am doing it by using 'optim'. Where some method ('BFGS., 'CG', 'SANN' etc) gives the result with warning but some does not. But do not understand the reason.

Comment: There is not enough info to help you. However, I am afraid this becomes more suited to stackoverflow.